# iOS metal 3d mesh vertex positions

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I would like to get the AABB of a 3d mesh rendered using metal API in real time.
I can get the boundingbox at loading time using MDLAsset.boundingBox  but I think I have to recalculate it myself after the rendering. So I would ike to know how get the vertex positions in real time to be able to calculte the box.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is your mesh animated at the vertex level (i.e., are you using skinners or morphers), or is only its transform animated?

Comment: No, a solide mesh that I make rotate or translate. Imagine the teapot mesh rotating, how find the max and min vertices to make the aabb box?. to find these two float3 I think I will need to go through all the vertices to find them. but how find this data of all vertices in real time?

Comment: It depends on how precise ("tight") you need the box to be. You could multiply the relevant transformation matrix by the corners of the model-space AABB to get an approximation of the AABB in world space (or camera space, or whatever you need). If you need the optimal box, though, you're right that you'll need to iterate the vertices instead. For what purpose do you need the AABB?

Comment: Indeed applying the same transfomrtaions to the MDLAsset.boundingBox that I get at the loading time,  in the update function gives a box which would be rather an OBB. AABB is much easier for conllisions where you don't need precsion but a binary answer.

Comment: Sorry; I meant to imply that you'd form an AABB by taking the extremal coordinates of the transformed corners of the original AABB. If that's "close enough" for your purposes, it's much cheaper than iterating/transforming all vertices. Also, are you using Swift?

Comment: Very interesting idea!! I really did not think to look by this side to the problem. I'm using swift. I try to see if I can go through your way.

Comment: Perfect, I have to thank you because your idea helped me to solve my problem. This question did not get its answer but its purpose had been attained. So I don't know how rate my own question : solved or not. I wonder. But I surely thank you.

Comment: Just happy to help :)